# Como colorir coluna tipo data de acordo com a data atual

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma tabela Excel de agendamentos, o que preciso que a cor vá mudando de acordo com a data,a data atual ficara com o tom de vermelho.

Se a data for maior que a data atual ficara vermelho também (Agendamento vencido).

Eu tentei a formatação condicional, mais não encontrei onde trabalhar com data nela.

Segue imagem de como seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já tentou esse link: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/17/excel-conditional-formatting-dates/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a formatação condicional, só que você invés de utilizar uma célula, você pode comparar à formula `HOJE()`

[image: Utilizando formatação condicional]

E se desejar ver outras formatações, tem esse link: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/17/excel-conditional-formatting-dates/

Comment: Perfeito,Obrigado !